# Finite number of recursions in Javascript with ES6 Y-combinator

Tags: javascript, recursion, y-combinator

I came across an answer to another SO question about recursion in Javascript, that gave a very terse form in ES6 using the Y-combinator, using ES6's fat arrow, and thought *hey, that'd be neat to use* - then 15 minutes or so later had circled back to *hm, maybe not*.

I've been to a few Haskell/Idris talks and run some code before, and familiar with standard JS, so was hoping I'd be able to figure this out, but can't quite see how a simple "do `n` recursions and return" is supposed to go, and where to implement a decrementing counter.

I just wanted to simplify getting the `n`<sup>th</sup> parent node of a DOM element, and there seem to be more dense explain-all guides than examples of simple applications like this.

The [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32851197/2668831) I first saw is:

```
const Y = a => (a => a(a))(b => a(a => b(b)(a)));
```

while [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43789397/2668831) more recent answer gives:

```
const U = f => f (f)
const Y = U (h => f => f (x => h(h)(f)(x)))
```

...which is given with examples of what the internal functions might be, and some example outputs, but introducing the U-combinator doesn't really help clarify this for me.

In the first example I can't really begin to understand what `b` might be in my case - I know I need one function `a` to return the parent node:

```
const par = function(node) {
  return node.parentNode;
}
```

I came up with the below:

```
function RecParentNode(base_node, n) {
  // ES6 Y-combinator, via: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32851197/2668831
  // define immutable [const] functions `Y` and `fn` [`fn` uses `Y`]
  // the arguments of `Y` are another two functions, `a` and `b`
  const Y = par=>(par=>par(par))(b=>par(par=>b(b)(par)));
  const fn = Y(fn => n => {
    console.log(n);
    if (n > 0) {
      fn(n - 1);
    }
  });
}
```

but then couldn't see what to do with the spare `b` lying around, and was about to delete it all and just forget I bothered.

All I'd like is to apply the `par` function `n` times, since the only alternatives I'm aware of are chaining `.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode`... or cheating and turning a string into an `eval` call.

Hoping someone familiar with functional JS could help me get the idea here for how to use the Y-combinator to make this helper function `RecParentNode` - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If imperative programming is an option:

```
 function getParent(el, n){
   while(n--) el = el.parentNode;
   return el;
}
```

Using functional recursion you could do:

```
 const Y = f => x => f (Y (f)) (x); // thanks to @Naomik
 const getParent = Y(f => el => n => n ? f(el.parentNode)(n - 1) : el);

 console.log(getParent(document.getElementById("test"))(5));
```

---

Lets build this Y-Combinator from the ground up.
As it calls a function by the Y-Combinator of itself, the Y-Combinator needs a reference to itself. For that we need a U-Combinator first:

```
 (U => U(U))
```

Now we can call that U combinator with our Y combinator so that it gets a self reference:

```
 (U => U(U))
 (Y => f => f( Y(Y)(f) ))
```

However that has a problem: The function gets called with an Y-Combinator reference which gets called with a Y-Combinator reference wich gets called .... weve got Infinite recursion. [Naomik outlined that here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43777354/y-combinator-in-javascript/43789397#43789397). The solution for that is to add another curried argument(e.g. `x`) that gets called when the function is used, and then another recursive combinator is created. So we only get the amount of recursion we actually need:

```
 (U => U(U))
 (Y => f => x => f( Y(Y)(f) )(x) )
 (f => n => n ? f(n - 1): n)(10) // a small example
```

We could also restructure it like this:

```
 (f => (U => U(U))(Y => f(x => Y(Y)(x))))
 (f => n => n ? f(n - 1): n)(10) // a small example
```

To get your first snippet, so basically its the same thing just a bit reordered and obfuscated through shadowing.

So now another combinator gets only created when `f(n-1)` gets called, which only happens when `n?`, so weve got an exit condition now. Now we can finally add our node to the whole thing:

```
 (U => U(U))
 (Y => f => x => f( Y(Y)(f) )(x) )
 (f => el => n => n ? f(el.parentNode)(n - 1): el)
 (document.getElementById("test"))(10)
```

That would be *purely functional*, however that is not really useful as it is extremely complicated to use. If we store function references we dont need the U combinator as we can simply take the Y reference. Then we arrive at the snippet above.

Comment: aha! that's really nice - will take another look at the syntax tomorrow with this example, thanks

Answer (score 4):

**due diligence**

Hey, that answer you found is mine! But before looking at various definitions of the *Y* combinator, we first review its purpose: (emphasis mine)

> In functional programming, the Y combinator can be used to formally define recursive functions **in a programming language that doesn't support recursion** ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Fixed_point_combinators_in_lambda_calculus))

Now, let's review your question

> I just wanted to simplify getting the nth parent node of a DOM element, and there seem to be more dense explain-all guides than examples of simple applications like this.

JavaScript supports direct recursion which means functions can call themselves directly by name. No use of *U* or *Y* combinators is necessary. Now to design a recursive function, we need to identify our **base** and **inductive** case(s)

- base case – `n` is zero; return the `node`
- inductive case 1 – `n` is *not* zero, but `node` is empty; we cannot get the parent of an empty node; return `undefined` (or some error if you wish)
- inductive case 2 - `n` is not zero and `node` is not empty; recur using the node's parent and decrement `n` by 1.

Below we write `nthParent` as a pure functional expression. To simplify the discussion to follow, we will define it function in [curried form](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32782922/633183).

```js
const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const nthParent = (node = Empty) => (n = 0) =>
  n === 0
    ? node
    : node === Empty
      ? undefined // or some kind of error; this node does not have a parent
      : nthParent (node.parentNode) (n - 1)
  
const Node = (value = null, parentNode = Empty) =>
  ({ Node, value, parentNode })

const data =
  Node (5, Node (4, Node (3, Node (2, Node (1)))))

console.log
  ( nthParent (data) (1) .value             // 4
  , nthParent (data) (2) .value             // 3
  , nthParent (data) (3) .value             // 2
  , nthParent (data) (6)                    // undefined
  )
```

**but what if...**

So suppose you were running your program with a JavaScript interpreter that did not support direct recursion... *now* you have a use case for the combinators

To remove the call-by-name recursion, we wrap our entire function in another lambda whose parameter `f` (or name of your choosing) will be the recursion mechanism itself. It is a drop-in replacement for `nthParent` –
 changes in **bold**

```
const nthParent = Y (f => (node = Empty) => (n = 0) =>
  n === 0
    ? node
    : node === Empty
      ? undefined
      : nthParent f (node.parentNode) (n - 1))
```

Now we can define *Y*

```
const Y = f =>
  f (Y (f))
```

And we can remove direct recursion in *Y* with *U* using a similar technique as before– changes in **bold**

```
const U = f =>
  f (f)

const Y = U (g => f =>
  f (Y U (g) (f)))
```

But in order for it to work in JavaScript, which uses [applicative order evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Applicative_order), we must delay evaluation using [eta expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#.CE.B7-conversion) – changes in **bold**

```
const U = f =>
  f (f)

const Y = U (g => f =>
  f (x =>  U (g) (f) (x)))
```

All together now

```js
const U = f =>
  f (f)
  
const Y = U (g => f =>
  f (x => U (g) (f) (x)))

const Empty =
  Symbol ()

const nthParent = Y (f => (node = Empty) => (n = 0) =>
  n === 0
    ? node
    : node === Empty
      ? undefined // or some kind of error; this node does not have a parent
      : f (node.parentNode) (n - 1))
  
const Node = (value = null, parentNode = Empty) =>
  ({ Node, value, parentNode })

const data =
  Node (5, Node (4, Node (3, Node (2, Node (1)))))

console.log
  ( nthParent (data) (1) .value             // 4
  , nthParent (data) (2) .value             // 3
  , nthParent (data) (3) .value             // 2
  , nthParent (data) (6)                    // undefined
  )
```

Now I hope you see why the Y combinator exists and why you wouldn't use it in JavaScript. In another answer, I attempt to help readers gain a deeper intuition about the Y combinator by use of a [mirror analogy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46821023/633183). I invite you to read it if the topic interests you.

**getting practical**

It doesn't make sense to use the Y combinator when JavaScript already supports direct recursion. Below, see a more practical definition of `nthParent` in uncurried form

```
const nthParent = (node = Empty, n = 0) =>
  n === 0
    ? node
    : node === Empty
      ? undefined // or some kind of error; this node does not have a parent
      : nthParent (node.parentNode, n - 1)
```

But what about those maximum recursion depth stack overflow errors? If we had a deep tree with nodes thousands of levels deep, the above function will produce such an error. In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43596323/633183) I introduce several ways to work around the problem. It *is* possible to write stack-safe recursive functions in a language that doesn't support direct recursion and/or [tail call elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)!